# Canvas is not showing

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, canvas

I want to draw an image with canvas. But the image is not showing up. If I try this code in JSFiddle, it works. I hope you can help me. Here is my script:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    img.src = "http://imageshack.us/a/img19/1158/tx2a.png";
};
```

This is how I place my canvas in the HTMl body:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1011" height="1700">Hier sollte eine Grafik sein</canvas>
```

And this is the working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5P2Ms/454/

I hope you can help me!

Full new HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


<script>
var can = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
  img.src = "http://imageshack.us/a/img19/1158/tx2a.png"; 
</script>


<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1011" height="1700">Hier sollte eine Grafik sein</canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I know, onload() is not supported by the canvas tag. 

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: No, there are no errors.

And I found this onload() in many examples. Are you sure that doesn't work?

Comment: @ChristophBeylage you wrote imageObj.onload. Change it to img.onload and try it. This should be working, at least worked on my local.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no window.onload in your full html. This is the problem

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
var can = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
  img.src = "http://imageshack.us/a/img19/1158/tx2a.png"; 
}
</script>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1011" height="1700">Hier sollte eine Grafik sein</canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Christoph you could also just move the <script> tag below the <canvas> element in the body tag. @BK you put the script outside of the head. did you mean to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the imageObj.onload is your problem:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
img.src = "http://imageshack.us/a/img19/1158/tx2a.png";
```

This works in JSFiddle with your HTML.
The problem is you call onload on a non-existant object, where I think you mean to run it on the image you instantiate to the variable img.

Update: This HTML should load the img for you.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var can = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
            var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            }
            img.src = "http://imageshack.us/a/img19/1158/tx2a.png";
        }
    </script>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1011" height="1700">Hier sollte eine Grafik sein</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Same problem with my code. It works in JSFiddle, but it doesn't work, when I create my own html document :(

Comment: Can you show me the entire HTML document? It might be the window.onload that's throwing you off balance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are trying to use a canvas in your script before you declare it in html (accessed by script but HTML-parser did not loaded this element). So, in this case, `document.getElementById('myCanvas')` is null, and `can.getContext('2d')` throws exception error with message 'can is null'. To solve that you need to put `<canvas ...></canvas>` before that script which accesses that element or make this script executed when entire content is parsed and loaded just right the same way as 'Bjarke H. Søndergaard' and 'B.K.' suggested.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's unbelievable no one is telling that to display the chart we have to include chart.js as well!
Just add this and it will work:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ? it is not a chart, it is a png image.